# Having issues making the page responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

What I need is for the page to be fully responsive and for some reason it isn't.

[image: Desktop View]

Mobile view
[image: Mobile View]

Here's the CSS and HTML.  We are generating the page using React.

```css
/* CSS Document  */

/*
@font-face {
    font-family: futura;
    src: url("../fonts/Futura-Book.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: futura italic;
    src: url("../fonts/Futura_ICG_Book_Oblique.ttf");
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
*/

/*--------------------------------ALL PAGES----------------------------------------*/

/*Body Style*/

* {
  font-family: futura, verdana;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  font-family: futura, verdana;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 600px;
}
/*NAVIGATION STYLE*/

nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4a486d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 950px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4a486d;
}
#search {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav a:visited {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
/*JUMBOTRON STYLE*/

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
/*CONTAINER STYLE*/

.container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f4f9;
  padding: 2%;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*BACKGROUND COLOR*/

#backcol {
  background-color: #f5f4f9;
  height: 100%;
}
/*LEFT LINKS STYLING*/

#sidenav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 16%;
  background-color: #f5f4f9;
  position: absolute;
  height: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  padding: 8px 0 0px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#leftNavPadding {
  padding: 10px;
}
#searchbar {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 1px;
}
#quick {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
/*PIC STYLING*/

#pic {
  width: 50%;
  stroke: #8e8db7;
  stroke-width: 4;
  margin: auto;
}
#pic2 {
  width: 30%;
  stroke: #8e8db7;
  stroke-width: 4;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 57px;
}
/*BUTTON STYLE*/

button {
  background-color: #6e6e9a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.vpButton {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.profilesButton {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/*FORM STYLE*/

form {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
label.formLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#fieldset {
  margin-top: -30px;
  border: 2px solid #515078;
}
#legend {
  color: #515078;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#fieldsetBorder {
  border: 1px dotted #8685a7;
}
#fieldsetBorder2 {
  border: 1px dashed #8685a7;
}
#legendLeft {
  text-align: left;
}
.astrex {
  color: red;
}
.trcolor {
  background-color: #8a87a2;
}
/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background-color: #b1b2d2;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
footer p {
  margin-right: 140px;
}
#footlogo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 190px;
}
/*SOCIAL MEDIA BUTTONS IN FOOTER*/

.socialMediaButtons {
  float: right;
  margin: 1%;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
.socialMediaButtons:hover {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
/*CONTAINER STYLE*/

#containerWidth {
  width: 960px;
}
/*PROFILE PAGE STYLE*/

#title {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#title2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#title3 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.topPad {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.bottomMargin {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}
.empty {
  height: 20px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------INDEX PAGE----------------------------------------*/

#topDiv {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #555b8f;
}
#arrow1 {
  height: 55%;
  width: 55%;
}
#introheading {
  font-family: futura bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  top: 40%;
  right: 18%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
#introtext {
  width: 26%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right: 16%;
  float: right;
  font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#bottomDiv {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #555b8f;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
#bottomArrow {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 55%;
  width: 55%;
}
#heading2 {
  font-family: futura bold;
  color: white;
  left: 150px;
  top: 130px;
  position: relative;
}
#secondHeading {
  font-size: 70px;
}
#endtext {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  top: 180px;
  font-family: futura;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#heximg {
  left: 170px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#hexstyle {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------LOGIN PAGE START----------------------------------------*/

#divContainer2 {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#introDiv {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 120px;
  background-image: url(../img/login.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 550px 550px;
}
/*BUTTON STYLING*/

.buttonlayout {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 3.5px 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: futura;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#guestButton {
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: -3.5px -3px;
}
.displayBlock {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 3.5px 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: futura;
}
#logInDiv {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-image: url(../img/login.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 550px 550px;
}
#logInForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
}
input.form {
  font-family: futura italic;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6e6e9a;
}
#registerDiv {
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../img/login.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 550px 550px;
}
#registerForm {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
/*--------------------------------LOGIN PAGE FINISH----------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------MY PROFILE----------------------------------------*/

/* hide nav button */

#hide {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*HEXAGON PROFILE IMAGE STYLING*/

svg {
  width: 19%;
  stroke: #8e8db7;
  stroke-width: 4;
}
#profileInfo {
  width: 90%;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #8a83d1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
.profileback {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f4f9;
  padding: 2%;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  width: 54px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------POD SEARCH PAGE START---------------------------------------*/

#basictxt {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#quote {
  text-align: left;
  color: #4a486d;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
.hireButton {
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#hireSize {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
/*--------------------------------POD SEARCH PAGE FINISH---------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------POD PROFILE PAGE START----------------------------------------*/

#enquire {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
#divContainer {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f5f4f9;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#skills {
  width: 330px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #6e6e9a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#skilllist {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#bio {
  width: 330px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #8a83d1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
#workHistory {
  width: 330px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: #6a6cae;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
/*--------------------------------POD PROFILE PAGE FINISH---------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------BOOK NOW PAGE START----------------------------------------*/

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input.form1 {
  font-family: futura italic;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6e6e9a;
}
#booknowFieldset {
  border: 1px dashed;
}
/*--------------------------------BOOK NOW PAGE FINISH----------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------CURRENT BOKINGS PAGE START---------------------------------------*/

#currentBookingTable,
.bookingtr,
.bookingtd {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.bookingtd {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
/*--------------------------------CURRENT BOKINGS PAGE FINISH---------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------HISTORIC BOOKING----------------------------------------*/

#Table,
th,
td {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*TABLE STYLING*/

table,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
td {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 300%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
th {
  padding: 10px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------CONTACT US----------------------------------------*/

input.inputstyle {
  font-family: futura italic;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6e6e9a;
}
#color {
  background-color: white;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
var Content = React.createClass({ render: function() { return (

<div>
  <div id="topDiv">
    <img src="img/arrow1.png" alt="logo" id="arrow1" />
    <h1 id="introheading">Hello, Welcome to Pod</h1>
    <div id="introtext">
      <p>SharpFutures is a social enterprise that supports young people into employment in the creative digital sector. By offering a range of interventions including Apprenticeships, Work Experience and Volunteering, SharpFutures nurture the transition
        into work, whilst responding to the fluctuating needs of creative digital businesses. We seed ideas through services for education, nurture the best talent by offering employment opportunities and real work experience, and we grow through the
        sale of this services.
        <br/>
      </p>
      <p>SharpFutures is a social enterprise that supports young people into employment in the creative digital sector. By offering a range of interventions including Apprenticeships, Work Experience and Volunteering, SharpFutures nurture the transition
        into work, whilst responding to the fluctuating needs of creative digital businesses. We seed ideas through services for education, nurture the best talent by offering employment opportunities and real work experience, and we grow through the
        sale of this services.
        <br/>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomDiv">
    <img src="img/arrow2.png" alt="logo" id="bottomArrow" />
    <div id="heading2">
      <h2 id="secondHeading">Like what <br/> you see?</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="endtext">
      <p>SharpFutures is a social enterprise that supports young people into employment in the creative digital sector. By offering a range of interventions including Apprenticeships, Work Experience and Volunteering, SharpFutures nurture the transition
        into work, whilst responding to the fluctuating needs of creative digital businesses. We seed ideas through services for education, nurture the best talent by offering employment opportunities and real work experience, and we grow through the
        sale of this services.
        <br/>
      </p>
      <p>POD is a pool creatives able to provide important, flexible support to fledgling and fast-growing businesses in the creative digital sector. With members recruited and retained based on a desire to develop sector-relevant skills, SharpFutures POD
        offer clients the opportunity to bring on board temporary, support staff while also playing a valuable part in young peopleâ€™s career development. Committing to a new full-time team member may be a stretch for small businesses, whereas having
        had the opportunity to â€˜try before you buyâ€™ can give employers confidence to commit.
      </p>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div id="heximg">
        <img id="hexstyle" src="img/hex2.png" alt="logo" />
        <br/>
        <img id="hexstyle" src="img/hex2.png" alt="logo" />
        <br/>
        <img id="hexstyle" src="img/hex2.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

)} }); ReactDOM.render(


<Content />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

What I need to know is how I get the page to be responsive without it looking awful.  Any advice or help with this would be appreciated.  We've been trying for days now and came up with nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you guys tried css media queries?

Comment: you can control it by media query css for mobile screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of very specific sizes and widths and heights in your CSS file, which is great, if there was only one screen size.

What is generally recommended is that you choose to use either:

Break-points and media queries, wherein which you specify screen size(s) and use the media queries to change the size/placement of certain screen elements.

OR, you could go with:

Relative sizing (ie. percentages or EM sizing units) with media queries.

Here is a link to some example code:

[css-tricks.com - Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your CSS first. For a responsive website you need to write everything in percentage. As I noticed you have written many height, width, padding etc. in pixels(px).

Updating them all with % will help you to make it responsive.

Post that you need to use media files for particular screen size. I suggest you to use % instead to px and to do Google how to use media files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the absolute positioning making a element be over content and isn't fixed automatically. Make the elements dynamic, then use [@media screen and..](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) in CSS3 to make the layout responsible.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing your desktop view in mobiles. It is obvious that somewhere you will find broken or overridden UI elements.
So you can customize your design by using media queries and viewport to make designs fit to your resolution.
For example you can reduce font sizes and image sizes and their positions.

Hope it helps.